# Extjs pie callout lines are not displayed

Tags: extjs, charts, pie-chart

I created a pie in extjs but callout line are not displayed, see following screenshots and code :

This is my actual pie :

[image]

This is what i want :

[image]

and this is my code :

```
Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
             renderTo: 'infos2',
             width: 500,
             height: 300,
             animate: true,
             store: store2,
             series: [
             {
               type: 'pie',
               highlight: {
                   segment: {
                     margin: 20
                   }
                 },
               field: 'population',
               label: {
                 field: 'state',
                 display: 'outside',
                 font: '12px Arial',
                 calloutLine: {
                        width: 5,
                        length: 30
                 }
               }
             }
             ]
          });
```

Comment: what's the ext version?

Comment: I think calloutLine was only added in 4.2.2

Comment: @Yellen Ok and there is no other way to do the same work ? I have to upgrade my version ?

Comment: If upgrade is not an option then you can check the implementation for calloutLine and add the same implementation in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comment of Yellen, calloutLine has been added on the 4.2.2 version of extjs